# Update macro in vba

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, for-loop

I created this macro to search through two spreadsheets and update one from the other based on unique keys that each row has.  It will copy the first sheet to a temp sheet then unfilter and unhide everything.  Next it will sort them by key so that they are all in order. after that it will move two columns to be excluded from the update to the front and update the rest.  To update it will search through using the match function and if it comes up as an error (which means the row isn't there) it will add it to the end of the update sheet.  Otherwise, it will copy and paste each row from the source to the update sheet.  It all works but for some reason it won't update past line 24 and I have no idea why.  I've stepped through it and it doesn't break, it just doesn't update.  I am new to vba so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub crossUpdate()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng1Row As Range, rng2Row As Range, Key As Range, match As Variant
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim endRng2 As Long

Set wb2 = Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2.xlsm")
Set wb1 = Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2 ESI.xlsm")

'Unfilter and Unhide both sheets
With wb1.Sheets("Development Priority List")
.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
With wb2.Sheets("Development Priority List")
.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

'Copy and paste original sheet to new temp sheet
wb1.Sheets("Development Priority List").Activate
wb1.Sheets("Development Priority List").Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add.Name = "SourceData"
wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Paste

N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)
Set rng1Row = rng1.EntireRow

'Sort temp sheet by key
wb1.Worksheets("SourceData").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    wb1.Worksheets("SourceData").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Cells.Range("A2:A" & N), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With wb1.Worksheets("SourceData").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:Z1000")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

'Sort update sheet by key
wb2.Activate
wb2.Worksheets("Development Priority List").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    wb2.Worksheets("Development Priority List").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=wb2.Sheets("Development Priority List").Cells.Range("A2:A" & N), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With wb2.Worksheets("Development Priority List").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:Z1000")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

'Dev columns moved on SourceData sheet
wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Activate
Columns("F:G").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight


'Dev columns moved on update sheet
wb2.Sheets("Development Priority List").Activate
Columns("F:G").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight


'Update sheet searched and updated from SourceData
Set rng2 = wb2.Sheets("Development Priority List").Cells.Range("C2:C" & N)
endRng2 = rng2.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To rng1.Rows.Count + 1
    Set Key = wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Range("C" & i)
    match = Application.match(Key, rng2, 0)
'Rows that don't exsist in update sheet are added
    If IsError(match) Then
        wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Range("C" & i, "Z" & i).Copy
        wb2.Sheets("Development Priority List").Range("C" & endRng2, "Z" & endRng2).Select
        wb2.Sheets("Development Priority List").Paste
        endRng2 = endRng2 + 1
'All other rows are scanned for changes
    Else
        For j = 3 To wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Range("C" & i, "Z" & i).Columns.Count
            wb2.Sheets("Development Priority List").Cells(j, i).Value = wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Cells(j, i)
        Next j


    End If

Next i

'SourceData sheet deleted
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Dev columns moved back on update sheet
wb2.Sheets("Development Priority List").Activate
Columns("A:B").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

wb1.Activate
```

Comment: At a quick glance, could it be that your Variable "N" is 24. Put a break point on the line just following where you assign "N" and check the value of "N" in the Locals window.

Comment: You've asked [a number of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4095610/user4095610) here, but have not yet accepted any answers (even though those answers appear to have been integrated in to this final version of your macro...). As a matter of ettiquette, you might consider *upvoting* the helpful answers, or ["**Accepting**" those that truly helped you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) solve your problem.

Comment: Ok @DavidZemens I will.

Comment: @JNevill, The value of N is 134 all the way through...

Comment: Your final nested For statement that sets the value of J is determined by the number of Columns in the Range("C" & i, "Z" & i)  I'm having difficulty following what that is doing since I can't see your data, but it looks like then the value of "J" is used to go through the Rows of the two worksheets inside that for loop. Is "J" only getting set to 24?

Comment: No it is not. It is set to the number of columns in the range specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a few times coming back to this to figure out what was wrong. Here is what I believe is happening:

This code:

```
For j = 3 To wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Range("C" & i, "Z" & i).Columns.Count
  wb2.Sheets("Development Priority List").Cells(j, i).Value = wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Cells(j, i)
Next j
```

Is looping from 3 to the number of columns between "C" and "Z" (ALWAYS 24). The bit inside the FOR loop is using `Cells(<row>, <column>)` syntax to copy from one cell to another. Because J is always looping from 3 to 24 then ROWS 3 through 24 are the only ones that will be updated. Perhaps you meant `Cells(i,j)`?